# Correct JavaScript 6 type to use for c# equivalent of struct

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, data-structures

I'm still getting used to working with JavaScript after many years of working mostly in C#.

I have an object that I'd like to instantiate.  The object always has the same 7 fields in it.  It's used to easily pass a set of 7 numbers around to various functions.

```
var myObj = { 
    4: 0,
    6: 0,
    8: 0,
    10: 0,
    12: 0,
    20: 0,
    100: 0
};
```

In EMCAScript 6, `class`es have been defined, but from what I've found on the web, `class`es seem mostly used for defining `function`s on a `class`, similar to the `prototype` of an EMCAScript 5 `function`, and not for defining fields.

What's the proper way to do this?

My thinking right now is it's something like:

```
var myObj = function () {
    this[4] = 0;
    this[6] = 0;
    this[8] = 0;
    this[10] = 0;
    this[12] = 0;
    this[20] = 0;
    this[100] = 0;
};

var obj = new myObj();
```

I don't believe this is a matter of opinion.  In most languages, there is a *right* way to do this.

The way you would do this in C# is

```
struct MyObj {
    public int Fours { get; set; }
    public int Sixes { get; set; }
    public int Eights { get; set; }
    public int Tens { get; set; }
    public int Twelves { get; set; }
    public int Twenties { get; set; }
    public int Hundreds { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just have an object, such as your first snippet?

Comment: per your edit... If you go by the notion that all "best practices" are really just accepted opinions, the "right" way or "proper" way is always just an opinion.

Comment: Have you considered naming your numbers in some meaningful way?

Comment: Javascript is a prototypal language.  In my opinion, that prototypal nature shouldn't be worked around; it should be embraced.  No, I don't think it's an opinion either.  Classes were added to the language to make it more familiar to classicists, but that doesn't mean it's the best way.

Comment: If you wanted to make it re-usable by passing in parameters to your function to initialize the variables the second approach would be the way to go.

Comment: Gah.  Don't punctuate your edits by putting EDIT in your posts.  This isn't a forum.  All posts here have a detailed edit history that anyone can view.  The edit history for this post is located [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29857143/revisions).

Comment: @bhspencer They are meaningful.  The numbers represent the number of sides on a die.  I'm making a D&D app.

Comment: If this is really just a set of numbers why not use an array

Comment: Ah, I was thinking about how I'd never seen properties that are a number (since it's not allowed in c#)

Comment: @bhspencer I could use an array, but I'm not a huge fan of remembering which index associates to which die.  0 -> 4, 1 -> 6... it'd make my code harder to read.

Comment: e.g. `var dice = [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 100];`

Comment: Every object in Javascript is an associative array anyway.  It's just an object.

Comment: Just because your using an array doesn't mean you have to use every index. `var die = []; die[4] = somevalue;`

Comment: @bhspencer It would be more like `var dice = [0 3 1 0 0 0 0]` to represent the equivalent `{ 4: 0, 6: 3, 8: 1, 10: 0, 12:0, 20: 0, 100:0 }`.

Comment: @KevinB Wouldn't that mean passing around arrays of size 100 with at most 7 useful values in them?

Comment: Arrays in Javascript are sparse arrays (more or less).  They're not true arrays; the closest analog is a hashtable.  When you supply them with a numeric index, Javascript converts that index to a string and looks up the appropriate key/value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to create an object in javascript which is similar to the struct you specified and be able to reuse that object, try creating a function that returns the template of the object:

```
function createMyObj() {

    return { 
        "4": 0,
        "6": 0,
        "8": 0,
        "10": 0,
        "12": 0,
        "20": 0,
        "100": 0
    };

}
```

There are many different creational patterns in javascript, it just depends on your needs. Do you need an object hierarchy? Then use the prototype pattern. Do you need an object creation that takes in default paramaters, sort of like a constructor? Then use an implementation similar to the one I specified above but modify it to accept a defaultValues object which contains some or all of the properties you need to specifiy.

Comment: In terms of best practices, I would suggest you stick to valid JavaScript names (specifically, not starting with numbers)

Comment: In my particular case, it's very helpful to use numbers as the keys, since I can just take random numbers from `1..key` `dice[key]` times and add them together.

Comment: Here is an approach using Sal's answer as a starting point that includes rolling, and outputting http://jsfiddle.net/9krsdpt0/6/

Answer (score 2):

The "best" way is pretty subjective. You'll see different answeres here and all over the web. Looking at your C# example, if you're goal is to replicate something similar to that class in an object orientated fashion, this might be a good starting point

```
function MyObj () { 
    this.Fours = 0;
    this.Sixes = 0;
    this.Eights = 0;
    this.Tens = 0;
    this.Twelves = 0;
    this.Twenties = 0;
    this.Hundreds = 0;
    this.RollDice = function() {
        console.log('here is a function')
    }
};
```

---

Sample usage

```
var myObj = new MyObj();

console.log(myObj); // -- MyObj {Fours: 0, Sixes: 0, etc...

myObj.RollDice();   // -- here is a function
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9krsdpt0/)

Comment: Since we're talking about best practices, [adding the function to the prototype](http://jsfiddle.net/9krsdpt0/1/) would be better.

Comment: I'd agree with that. Like I said, many options. Comparing to a C# class, though, in this style, `this.RollDice` would just about mirror a `void RollDice()` method I'd define after my fields. Anyways, interesting in the least, OP will surely enjoy learning and exploring

Comment: I took your code and added some useful functions: http://jsfiddle.net/9krsdpt0/6/ to show how JavaScript can work as an object Oriented language.

Comment: @JasonSperske thanks for your input definitely some good stuff here!